# How can I subset specific genes from my dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 5911 cells (as the columns) with expression data from 22k genes (as the rows). I also have a vector of 100 specific genes. How can I subset the dataframe so that I can get only the 100 specific genes instead of all 22k genes?

I have tried
`newdf <- subset(df, subset = genelist)` but that gives me the error that " 'subset' must be logical". I'm not sure what to do and everything I googled hasn't helped either.

Sorry if this is a simple question, I am very new to using R.

Comment: Does the data frame contain a column with the gene names? Or are they stored in the row names of the data frame (you can check that using `rownames(df)`) ?

Answer (score 2):

You may need `%in%` to see if elements in the column `gene` are presented in the `genelist`, e.g.,

```
subset(df, subset = gene %in% genelist)
```

Comment: Or if the gene names are in the row names of the data frame: `subset(df, subset = rownames(df) %in% genelist)`

Comment: @neilfws that worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Good! I would accept the answer, it provides the basis for the solution.